# django-contact-form: How to use form submitter's email as the from_email

Tags: django

Using [django-contact-form](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-contact-form/), I have overridden the form class:

```
from contact_form.forms import ContactForm
from django.conf import settings

class ContactFormPublic(ContactForm):

    tuples = settings.WORKSHOP_ADMINS
    recipient_list = [mail_tuple[1] for mail_tuple in tuples]
    from_email = 'Joe Jones <joe@jones.org>'
```

That works, but I want the from_email to be that of the name and email submitted in the form itself. Tried referring to "self.email" in the form, but it complains that self is not defined. Seems like it should be simple, but I'm not able to tell from the documentation how to solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi. Can you please post your ContactForm class and also your view?

Comment: Brandon - Again, I'm using django-contact-form. So I have no custom view, and I'm subclassing the provided form. The goal of course is to extend django-contact-form without altering it (which it purports to be very good at, though the docs don't make it clear how to go about it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I took a look at the ContactForm class. The easiest way I can see to set the from_email to the email submitted in the form is to override ContactForm.get_messge_dict:

```
from contact_form.forms import ContactForm
from django.conf import settings

class ContactFormPublic(ContactForm):

    tuples = settings.WORKSHOP_ADMINS
    recipient_list = [mail_tuple[1] for mail_tuple in tuples]

    def get_message_dict(self):
        if not self.is_valid():
            raise ValueError("Message cannot be sent from invalid contact form")
        message_dict = {}

        """
        I removed 'from_email' from the message_part tuple check and updated the
        message_dict, setting the 'from_email' to the value of self.email
        """
        for message_part in ('message', 'recipient_list', 'subject'):
            attr = getattr(self, message_part)
            message_dict[message_part] = callable(attr) and attr() or attr
        message_dict.update({'from_email' : getattr(self, 'email')})

        return message_dict
```

Hope that helps you out.

Comment: Many thanks Brandon! Much appreciated. I did make one tweak so it generates a reply-to with the full name intact: 

full_email = self.request.POST['name'] + '<' + self.request.POST['email'] + '>'
message_dict.update({'from_email' : full_email})